# react-sortablejs - Setting the 'onChange' method on an object with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sortablejs

I'm using the [react-sortablejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortablejs) library.
When trying to move cards within the list. I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I have a dense structure and it gets lost here. How to handle `onChange` so that I can see in the console that the order of the notes within the list has changed.

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ra4spr)

```
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';

// Functional Component
const SortableList = ({ items, onChange }) => {  
    return (
        <div>
          <Sortable
            tag="ul"
            onChange={(order, sortable, evt) => {
              console.log(order)
              onChange(order);
            }}

          >
            {items.listItems.map(val => {
             return <li key={uniqueId()} data-id={val}>List Item:  {val.title}</li>})
            }
          </Sortable>
        </div>
    );
};

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
       item: {
        id: "abc123",
        name: "AAA",
        lists: [
          {
            id: "def456", 
            list_id: "654wer",
            title: 'List1',
            desc: "description",
            listItems: [
              {
                id: "ghj678", 
                title: "ListItems1",
                listItemsId: "88abf1"
              },
              {
                id: "poi098", 
                title: "ListItems2",
                listItemsId: "2a49f25"
              },
              {
                id: "1oiwewedf098", 
                title: "ListItems3",
                listItemsId: "1a49f25dsd8"
              }
            ]   
          },
          {
            id: "1ef456", 
            list_id: "654wer",
            title: 'List 2',
            desc: "description",
            listItems: [
              {
                id: "1hj678", 
                title: "ListItems4",
                listItemsId: "18abf1"
              },
              {
                id: "1oi098", 
                title: "ListItems5",
                listItemsId: "1a49f25"
              },
              {
                id: "1oiwewe098", 
                title: "ListItems6",
                listItemsId: "1a49f25dsd"
              }
            ]   
          },
          {
            id: "2ef456", 
            title: 'List 3',
            list_id: "254wer",
            desc: "description",
            listItems: [
              {
                id: "2hj678", 
                title: "ListItems7",
                listItemsId: "28abf1"
              },
              {
                id: "2oi098", 
                title: "ListItems8",
                listItemsId: "234a49f25"
              },
              {
                id: "df098", 
                title: "ListItems9",
                listItemsId: "1asd8"
              }
            ]   
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    render() {
      const c = this.state.item['lists'].map(item => { return item.listItems});

        return (
          this.state.item['lists'].map(item => {       
            return  (<div>
                      {item.title}
                      <SortableList
                        key={uniqueId()}
                        items={item}
                        onChange={(item) => {
                          console.log(item)
                          this.setState({item});
                        }}
                      >
                      </SortableList>
                    </div>)
          })
        )
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why first `onChange` is calling itself?

Comment: @NicolòCozzani I pass `item` from `this.state.item['lists'].map(item => {`. `Item` is object, but I have to pass array

Comment: you have to remove `onChange(order);` after first `console.log()`

Comment: also you do not need to specify `onChange()` on the `render` function

Comment: @NicolòCozzani When I delete `on Change (order)`, the order of the cards does not change

Comment: @NicolòCozzani It won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update few changes in your code.

Update the `SortableList` function as below.

First pass `data-id={val.id}` in `li` and after that in `onChange` method you will receive the `order` with `id`. So based on that we are sorting the records.

```
const SortableList = ({ items, onChange }) => {  
    return (
        <div>
          <Sortable
            tag="ul"
            onChange={(order, sortable, evt) => {
              items.listItems.sort(function(a, b){
                  return order.indexOf(a.id) - order.indexOf(b.id);
              });
              onChange(items);
            }}
          >
            {items.listItems.map(val => {
             return <li key={uniqueId()} data-id={val.id}>List Item:  {val.title}</li>})
            }
          </Sortable>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Update the `onChange` event of `App` component.

```
onChange={(item) => {
  let itemObj = {...this.state.item};
  itemObj.lists.map(x=>{
    if(x.id === item.id) x = item;
  });
  this.setState({itemObj});
}}
```

That's it!

Here is the working demo for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sortablejs-blzxwd

Comment: Can you explain how to change and update two groups. Your example is working in two seperate sortable and sorting... but if I want to update group state.

Answer (score 0):

When remove the `onChange` event in the `Sortable` list, Its works.

```
const SortableList = ({ items, onChange }) => {  
    return (
        <div>
          <Sortable
            tag="ul"
          >
            {items.listItems.map(val => {
             return <li key={uniqueId()} data-id={val}>List Item:  {val.title}</li>})
            }
          </Sortable>
        </div>
    );
};
```

[image]

Comment: And where to put console.log to see that the order is changing?